How to add 'Then print response' automatically at the end of every scenario in karate tests
I want to add 'Then Print response' statement at the end of every karate test scenario but do not want to explicitly write in every scenario. Tried with 'Afterscenario' hook but that does not work as it does not remember the request sent in the scenario when afterscenario statements are run. Is there any way to achieve this?

I don't understand why you need this, and no one has asked for this before. By default Karate logs all responses in the HTML report and most teams are happy with this.
Maybe you need to look at the RuntimeHook: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+runtimehook


Reports include HTTP request and response logs in-line, which makes troubleshooting and debugging easier

Refer - https://github.com/karatelabs/karate?tab=readme
